# Want to make my UIScrollView be infinite (like dates in a calendar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, calendar

I have a UIScrollView like so:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
}
[scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

This is the right gestures I want and is fine for a finite set of custom subviews, but how do I make the scollview go infinite?

I want the subviews to be dates and swiping left and right will bring the next or previous date.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView` and adjust your view positions and the scrollviews content offset there, or have a look at Apple's example on how to create a infinite horizontal ScrollView by subclassing the `UIScrollView`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/